# Does Salesforce allows to have duplicate Picklist values?

Tags: picklist

As a System Admin, my requirement is to add duplicate picklist values to different picklist API names as shown below. I need to change

**FROM**

[image]

**TO**

[image]

Can both the picklist API values's N and MN have the same picklist value Mentor as stated in the above example? Is there any work around in Salesforce to have duplicate picklist values for the same API name?

I first,

1. Deactivated the picklist value Mentor N
2. Edited Picklist value MN - changed picklist value from MN to Mentor.
3. On trying to Reactivate the picklist value Mentor N, resulted in below error in Salesforce

**ERROR IN Salesforce**

**Data Not Available**
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

Can both the picklist API values's N and MN have the same picklist value Mentor as stated in the above example? Is there any work around in Salesforce to have duplicate picklist values for the same API name

Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Well, I am just curious about how will the end-users differentiate between these two values, if this is possible and done, they will see two  picklist values as Mentor, Mentor. How will they know which one to select?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to deactivate the picklist MN rather change the value of MN to Mentor, just editing the picklist.

Otherwise, from translation workbench change the translation of MN for English language to Mentor.

It will work.